# SingleOrDefault in generic repository?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I implement repository pattern in my current web api project with EF6. Currently, I have the following function (in CustomerRepository) that returns a customer:

```
    public override Customer Get(int id, params Expression<Func<Customer , object>>[] include)
    {
        if (include.Any())
        {
            var set = include.Aggregate<Expression<Func<Customer , object>>, IQueryable<Customer >>
                        (dbset, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

            return dbset.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)
        }

        return dbset.Find(id);
    }
```

This works fine, but I would like to move the above method in my generic repository. The problem here is SingleOrDefault, because Id wouldn't be known for T.

Is there a way to solve this? Do I need to implement an interface?

As a side not, the first property of ALL of my entities is 'int Id'.

Comment: can you put your Repository code? i think you can do something like:  (public class Repository<T> where T: IKey), IKey is an interface containing Id property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works fine,

Hmmm, are you sure about that:

```
return dbset.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id = id)
```

shouldn't this be:

```
return dbset.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)
```

Anyway, if all your entities have an integer Id property, why not have them all implement an interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

and then you will constrain your generic T parameter to this interface in the base repo and you will know how to write the lambda.

Comment: I use Database First. Do I need to create partial classes for each and every entity that EF creates from the model?

Comment: no, just create an IKey interface containing Id only and let all classes implements this interface ( it will not change your model or your database creation)

Comment: Where in the EF designer can I set the inteface? It looks like I have to create a partial class for every entity.

Comment: you can do this idea ( partial classes), or simply modify the T4 template file and let all the entities to inherits from a base class and this base class implements the IKey interface

Comment: Yeah I figured that out. I will use partial classes instead of modifying the T4 templates.

Answer (score 1):

EF6 has a `Find()` method that sort of does what you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx

```
public T Get(int id)
{
    return dbset.Find(id);
}
```

Don't worry about it loading more joined tables (includes) than needed. It's not that big of a deal for a single record. EDIT: sorry, `Find` does not actually do any eager loading of its own. Related entities are only returned if they were already tracked by the context.

Answer (score 0):

this is my soution to use Expression

```
 public class EfGenericService<TEntity, TKey> : IGenericService<TEntity, TKey>
           where TEntity : class
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _entities;
        public EfGenericService(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
        _dbContext = context ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(context));
        _entities = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();

    }
    public async Task<TEntity?> FindSingleAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>predicate)
    {
        return await _entities.SingleOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
    }
    }
```